# dismissing camera and returning to app takes a long time

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an app lets user add his image. For this I use UIImagePicker.

Please take a look at the following function:
It opens a view as a popup when image is tapped.

```
func imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{


    let userDetails:Dictionary = (UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "myUserDetails") as? [String:Any])!
    let UserID:Int = userDetails["UserID"] as! Int

    let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "imager") as! imagerVC
    popOverVC.UserID = UserID

    self.addChildViewController(popOverVC)
    popOverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
    self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)

    popOverVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)


    popOverVC.callback = { image in
        // do something with the image


        self.profile_image.image = image
        if let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) {
            //save profile image as NewUserID
            UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: String(UserID))
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        }
    }  
}
```

This is the View code that activates the camera and this view is opened as popOverVC from the code above.

```
    import UIKit

    class imagerVC: UIViewController,  UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
        var UserID:Int = 0
        @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!
        var callback : ((UIImage) -> ())?

        @IBOutlet weak var btn_end: UIButton!
        @IBOutlet weak var from_camera: UIBarButtonItem!
        @IBOutlet weak var from_gallery: UIBarButtonItem!

        @IBAction func btn_end_pressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
             self.view.removeFromSuperview()
        }

        @IBAction func btn_closer(_ sender: UIButton) {
             self.view.removeFromSuperview()
        }


        @IBAction func photofromLibrary(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
            picker.allowsEditing = false
            picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            picker.mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .photoLibrary)!
            picker.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
            present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
            picker.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = sender
        }



        @IBAction func shootPhoto(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
            if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {

                UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "is_selfie")
                UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.picker.allowsEditing = false
                    self.picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
                    self.picker.cameraCaptureMode = .photo
                    self.picker.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
                    self.present(self.picker,animated: true,completion: nil)
                }

            } else {
                noCamera()
            }    
        }


        let picker = UIImagePickerController()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            picker.delegate = self   
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }


        //MARK: - Delegates
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])
        {
            let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
            myImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit //3
            myImageView.image = chosenImage //4


            myImageView.layer.borderWidth = 1
            myImageView.layer.masksToBounds = false
            myImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            myImageView.layer.cornerRadius = myImageView.frame.height/4
            myImageView.clipsToBounds = true

            callback?(chosenImage)

            dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil)  
        }

        func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        func noCamera(){
            let alertVC = UIAlertController(
                title: "No Camera",
                message: "Sorry, this device has no camera",
                preferredStyle: .alert)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(
                title: "OK",
                style:.default,
                handler: nil)
            alertVC.addAction(okAction)
            present(
                alertVC,
                animated: true,
                completion: nil)
        }       
}
```

I have two problems. Maybe they are related.
The main problem is that after the camera view loads and the picture is taken, When I press the button Use photo, the camera does not get dismissed at once and there is a lag of about a minute till the camera view is dismissed. The callback function by the way get triggered as soon "use photo" button is pressed.

I am not sure if this is connected but I get the following warning:
Instance method 'imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)' nearly matches requirement yet when i let Xcode autocorrect me the camera functionality ceases to function.

I tried wrapping the line
 dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil)
in DispatchQueue.main.async  to make it run on main thread but that did not work

Not sure why but lag does not occur in physical IPad, only iPhone devices

Any help rendered is greatly appreciated

Comment: Where is imageTapped func called? Could that be in background thread?

Answer (score -1):

this is as expected behaviour on simulators. It should not lag on device and as you said its working on device then its cool. !!!

Comment: behavior is on physical devices. 3 iphone 6